# Error while renaming the column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, alter-table

I have created new table by:

```
CREATE TABLE DIFF_ODATE_PERIOD AS
select test_3.odate - test_3.max_period from test_3;
```

And it gave me column name: `?column?`
And when I am trying to change the name it gives me error:

```
  ALTER TABLE DIFF_ODATE_PERIOD
  RENAME COLUMN ?column? TO test;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?" LINE 71:   RENAME COLUMN ?column?
> TO test;

Can I define the name while creating or after?

Comment: Do you need to put quotes around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to alias that column directly in the `create table ... as select` statement:

```
create table diff_odate_period as
select odate - max_period as test from test_3;
```